# How to format data inside array_agg?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select 
    w.workspace_id,
    w.owner_id,
    array_agg(u)
from workspaces w
inner join workspace_relations wr on wr.workspace_id = w.workspace_id
inner join users u on u.user_id = wr.addressee_id
group by w.workspace_id
```

The result is:

```
workspace_id | owner_id | {"(concatenated data f.e: userIdusernameemailpassword)"}
```

I want to select and format the data inside the last column so I can have a separate array of objects:

```
[{ userId: 'test', username: 'test' }, ...]
```

Comment: You can use `JSON_AGG` along  with `JSON_BULD_OBJECT`

Comment: Instead of `array_agg(u)`, what does `jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(u))` give you?

Answer (score 0):

I've used this line to solve the trouble: `json_strip_nulls(json_agg(json_build_object('user_id', u.user_id, 'username', u.username))) coworkers`